# Scheme syntax error when recursing

Tags: recursion, scheme

I'm writing a recursive function that will convert an expression from prefix to infix. However, I need to add in a check to make sure part of the input is not already in infix.

For example, I may get input like (+ (1 + 2) 3).
I want to change this to ((1 + 2) + 3)

Here is what I have so far:

```
 (define (finalizePrefixToInfix lst)
      ;Convert a given s-expression to infix notation
     (define operand (car lst))
     (define operator1 (cadr lst))
     (define operator2 (caddr lst))    
     (display lst)
     (cond 
         ((and (list? lst) (symbol? operand));Is the s-expression a list?
        ;It was a list. Recusively call the operands of the list and return in infix format
        (display "recursing")
        (list (finalizePrefixToInfix operator1) operand (finalizePrefixToInfix operator2))
    )
    (else (display "not recursing") lst);It was not a list. We can not reformat, so return.
)

)
```

However, this is giving me syntax errors but I cant figure out why. Any help?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the error you get from the interpreter. "syntax errors" doesn't say much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check to see if the `lst` parameter is a list at the very beginning (base  case), otherwise `car` and friends will fail when applied to an atom. Try this:

```
(define (finalizePrefixToInfix lst)
  (cond ((not (pair? lst)) lst)
        (else
         (define operand   (car lst))
         (define operator1 (cadr lst))
         (define operator2 (caddr lst))    
         (cond 
           ((symbol? operand)
            (list (finalizePrefixToInfix operator1)
                  operand
                  (finalizePrefixToInfix operator2)))
           (else lst)))))
```

Comment: Be aware that outside of Racket (basically any Scheme implementation where cons cells are mutable), `list?` is O(n). So usually I'm sparing with its use unless I know I'm on Racket.

Comment: Yep, better use `pair?` :)

Comment: Just 2 things. In the second `cond` we already know that `lst` is pair. And we should also check for the length to be safe, even though it's O(n).

Comment: @Rptx thanks for the feedback! I adopted your first suggestion. But I'll assume that the expression is well-formed, otherwise the code will look ugly with all the error checking :P

Comment: Well. OP's already giving it a half infix expression, a not 3 elements list doesn't seem improbable. But as you wish. You're very welcome.